# How can i after animated view move a views below? (without using Animation class)

Tags: android, android-animation

For animation i use a ViewPropertyAnimator.

```
mAnimatedView.animate().translationYBy(50).start();
```

Before translation:

[image]

After translation:

[image]

I want buttons to stay below AnimatedView (according to the mentioned above illustrations it is not right now). There is only one idea that comes to my mind: animate buttons too, but i am sure it is not the best solution. Maybe there is a  method that recalculates all layout while animation, that i have missed?

Comment: You should use RelatveLayout an animationListener. After animation you should set a new LayoutParams to ypur views.

Comment: But during the animation process the view still is covering the buttons, am i right?

Comment: Yes, you have a right. but you can create more animation than one. You should start animations for AnimatedView and for container of your button. And when animations will be finished you should change layout parameters of them.

p.s. sorry fo my English.

Comment: I mentioned this approach "There is only one idea that comes to my mind: animate buttons too, but i am sure it is not the best solution."
But it is not good idea i think...(

Comment: PS: English ok, i am from Russia so its quite normal)

Answer (score 0):

Add Buttons to xml before AnimatedView:

```
<Button ...>

<AnimatedView ...>
```